# Multiple UserManager with the same UserIdentity type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have a management app which I'd to connect to both my staging and dev databases, like follows:

```
    services.AddIdentity<UserIdentity, IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DevApplicationDbContext>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    
    services.AddIdentity<UserIdentity, IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<StagingApplicationDbContext>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

This results in

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Scheme already exists: Identity.Application'
```

I've seen examples how you can set up multiple UserManagers with *differing* UserIdentity types, but what  I need is the same types just different databases.

Comment: And how would you, logically, log someone in? Which database would you use?

Comment: @Marco I'd like to inject the relevant UserManager into the login service

Comment: That is not the answer to my question. Anyhow: Why do you want to mix dev and staging?

Comment: @Marco Currently I use my dev db to log users in. It's a management app only used by staff, I haven't decided which db to use long term.

I want to mix staging and dev and eventually production so I can view the data together without needing an internal API layer. ATM my service layer is shared between the management project and my app project.

Comment: That is a very bad idea. Captial VERY. You should have 3 distinct environments, that do not share any information between them.  If you mix dev with prod and something unforeseen happens, you are in neck deep.